# Azure B2C + Angular + ASP.NET Core 2.2 Hosted in Azure Re-authentication Timeout Issue

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

We are using a stack of Angular on the front end, ASP.NET Core + Azure B2C on the back end for authentication. The app is hosted in an App Service on Azure.

I'm noticing sometimes when I'll have the site up and it's been idle (say overnight) when I go attempt to click another link to pull back data, B2C looks like it'll will attempt to redirect I'm guessing to pickup claims/re-authenticate.  If I do a hard refresh I notice it kicks over to the B2C URL then redirects properly back to my app.

We simply have `[Authorize]` attributes on our Controllers to ensure they are authorized.

Any thoughts on the best way to handle this? Here are some of the key code areas on how we are doing this.

Is this more of a CORS issue? Additionally, is there anyway to extend "timeout" for authentication in this setup?

Error:

[image]

Code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = _ => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options))
            .AddCookie(x =>
            {
                x.Cookie.Name = UIConstants.WebSessionCookieName;
            });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(c =>
        {
            c.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync(
                    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/auth/signin" });

                return;
            }

            await next.Invoke();
        });

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";


            });
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is you are using cookie authentication. The front-end AJAX call is getting redirected to B2C. You could try to detect this situation in the front-end and then redirect the user, or you could switch to using JWT Bearer token authentication + MSAL.js.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have thoughts on how to detect this front end in angular and redirect? I’d hate to have to switch to JwT or something along those lines

Comment: Also how do I reliably extend the cookie?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but if you could disable the AJAX following redirects, then you could handle the 302 response in code, and detect that it is trying to redirect the browser to Azure AD.